# loop through and opening variables in an xarray dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am looking for a way to accessing and getting variables in an xarray dataset that can be included within a loop. I know that this code will list the variables name:

```
for ii in dataSet.data_vars:
    print(ii)
```

I am looking for something similar that allows me to open each variable within the loop.
I am new to python, migrating from Matlab, so detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Xarray objects have a [Dictionary interface](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/api.html#dictionary-interface) which can be used for this kind of operations. In your particular case, you probably want:

```
for var_name, values in dataSet.items():
    # code
```

To iterate over dictionaries, you can use `.items()`, `.keys()` or `.values()`, depending on what you want to achieve. See [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) for one example, there are many.

Comment: I ended up using `dataSet__getitem__(varname)` to access the variables through a loop. But many thanks for your reply, it will probably come handy for future issues

Comment: You can use `dataset[varname]`, you should not have to use `__getitem__` directly

Comment: FWIW  i had the same issue - this: `list(dataSet.data_vars)`  also works well and returns a list of  just the variable names.